# Jasper Plugin 1.11.0

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I'm trying to use the Jasper Plugin with the version 1.11.0 with the following `Build.config`:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" 
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") { }
    log "error" 
    checksums true 
    legacyResolve false
    repositories {
        inherits true 
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/"
        mavenRepo "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
    }
    dependencies {
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
        build "net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:4.0.0"
        build "net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:4.0.1"
        build "joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2"
        compile "com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7"
        build('org.grails:grails-docs:2.4.3') {
            excludes 'itext'
        }
    }
    plugins {
         build ":tomcat:7.0.55" 
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
        compile ":portal-core:1.7"
        compile ":platform-core:1.0.0" 
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"   
        compile ":spring-security-cas:2.0-RC1" 
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5"  
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        compile ":remote-pagination:0.4.8" 
        compile ":cxf-client:2.1.1"
        compile ":cxf:2.1.1" 
        compile ":jasper:1.11.0" 
    }
}
```

When I let grails getting the artifacts I'm getting an Forbidden (403) Error:

Could not transfer artifact org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3 from/to jaspersoft_artifactoryonline_com_jaspersoft_third-party-ce-artifacts_ (http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/): Forbidden (403)
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.

How do I resolve this Problem?

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.4.3

Comment: I try with a complete blank application, using Grails 2.4.3. I've copied your `BuildConfig.groovy` and all works well ... Are you sure that's not a network problem? And are you sure you need to add dependencies for `"net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:4.0.1"` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one as answered on today:

```
mavenRepo("https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/")
```